# Grouping Variables in Multilevel Linear Models

Tags: r, multi-level, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to learn hierarchical models in R and I have generated some sample data for myself. I am having trouble with the correct syntax for coding a multilevel regression problem.

I generated some data for salaries in a Business school. I made the salaries depend linearly on the number of years of employment and the total number of publications by the faculty member. The faculty are in various departments and I made the base salary(intercept) different for each department and also the yearly hike(slopes) different for each department. This way, I have the intercept (base salary) and slope(w.r.t experience in number of years) of the salary depend on the nested level (department) and slope w.r.t another explanatory variable (Publications) not depend on the nested level. What would be the correct syntax to model this in R?

here's my data

```
    Data <-data.frame(Sl_No = c(1:40),
    +                   Dept = as.factor(sample(c("Mark","IT","Fin"),40,replace = TRUE)),
    +                   Years = round(runif(40,1,10)))

    pubs <-round(Data$Years*runif(40,1,3))
    Data$Pubs <- pubs

    lookup_table<-data.frame(Dept = c("Mark","IT","Fin","Strat","Ops"),
    +                          base = c(100000,140000,150000,150000,120000),
    +                          slope = c(6000,5000,3000,2000,4000))

  Data <- merge(Data,lookup_table,by = 'Dept')
  salary <-Data$base+Data$slope*Data$Years+Data$Pubs*10000+rnorm(length(Data$Dept))*10000

    Data$base<-NULL
    Data$slope<-NULL
```

I have tried the following:

1)

```
 multilevel_model<-lmer(Salary~1|Dept+Pubs+Years|Dept, data = Data)
```

> Error in model.matrix.default(eval(substitute(~foo, list(foo = x[[2]]))),  : 
>    model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()

2)

```
multilevel_model<-lmer(`Salary`~ Dept + `Pubs`+`Years`|Dept , data = Data)
```

> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

I want to see the estimates of the salary intercept and yearly hike by Dept and the estimate of the effect of publication as a standalone (pooled). Right now I am not getting the code to work at all.

I know the base salary and the yearly hike by dept and the effect of a publication (since I generated it).

```
Dept    base    Slope
Fin     150000  3000 
Mark    100000  6000 
Ops     120000  4000
IT      140000  5000
Strat   150000  2000
```

Every publication increases the salary by 10,000.

**ANSWER:**
Thanks to @Ben 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517717/11927973)  I think the correct model is

```
    multilevel_model<-lmer(Salary~(1|Dept)+ Pubs +(0+Years|Dept), data = Data)
```

This gives me the following fixed effects by running

```
    summary(multilevel_model)
```

```
Fixed effects:
   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 131667.4    10461.0   12.59
Pubs         10235.0      550.8   18.58
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    Pubs -0.081
```

The Department level coefficients are as follows:

```
coef(multilevel_model)
```

```
$Dept
          Years (Intercept)     Pubs
Fin   3072.5133    148757.6 10235.02
IT    5156.6774    136710.7 10235.02
Mark  5435.8301    102858.3 10235.02
Ops   3433.1433    118287.1 10235.02
Strat  963.9366    151723.1 10235.02
```

These are pretty good estiamtes of the original values. Now I need to learn to assess "how good" they are. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to use `dput` to provide data.

Comment: comma marks in numbers are likely to be more trouble than they're worth in the long run.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. Fixed the original post to include code for generating data.

Comment: OK. does my answer  solve your problem?  You may find the `simulate.merMod` function useful: see the examples for a way to use it to simulate from a specified model

Comment: Yes it does :) Thanks a lot. I have added it as an edit to my question,with some answer data - not sure if this is the accepted practice on this site though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)

```
multilevel_model<-lmer(`Total Salary`~ 1|Dept + 
 `Publications`+`Years of Exp`|Dept , data = sample_data)
```

I can't immediately diagnose why this gives a syntax error, but parentheses are generally recommended around random-effect terms because the `|` operator has high precedence in formulas.  Thus the response/right-hand side (RHS) formula

```
~ (1|Dept) + (`Publications`+`Years of Exp`|Dept)
```

*might* work, except that it would be problematic because both terms contain the same intercept term: if you wanted to do this you'd probably need

```
~ (1|Dept) + (0+`Publications`+`Years of Exp`|Dept)
```

(2)

```
~ Dept + `Publications`+`Years of Exp`|Dept
```

It doesn't really make any sense to put the same variable (`Dept`) on both the left- and right-hand sides of the bar.

---

You should probably use

```
~ pubs + years_exp + (1 + years_exp|Dept)
```

Since *in principle* the effect of publication could vary across departments, the maximal model would be

```
~ pubs + years_exp + (1 + pubs + years_exp|Dept)
```

- It rarely makes sense to include a random effect without its corresponding fixed effect.
- Note that you may get singular fits even if you have the right model; see the `?isSingular` man page.
- if the 18 observations listed above represent your whole data set, it's very likely too small to fit the maximal model successfully. Rule of thumb is that you need 10-20 observations per parameter estimated, and the maximal model has (intercept + 2 fixed-effect params + (3*4)/2=6 random-effect parameters) = 9 parameters. (Since it's simulated, you can easily simulate a big data set ...)
- I'd recommend renaming variables in your data frame so you don't have to fuss with backtick-protecting variable names with spaces in them ...

The [GLMM FAQ has more on model specification](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification)

Comment: This FAQ was a wonderful resource. Thanks a lot. I think the second solution under (1) is _probably_ what i want, but I am unable to say for sure. I need to read up a bit more to figure this out. I tried this
        multilevel_model<-lmer(Salary~(1|Dept)+Pubs+(0+Years|Dept), data = Data)

Comment: output of summary
REML criterion at convergence: 841.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7167 -0.6334 -0.1313  0.6813  1.7533 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 Dept     (Intercept) 485873532 22043   
 Dept.1   Years        18185534  4264   
 Residual              92965436  9642   
Number of obs: 40, groups:  Dept, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 131667.4    10461.0   12.59
Pubs         10235.0      550.8   18.58

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Pubs -0.081